# how to inject function to other class in flutter

Tags: function, flutter, methods, dart, inject

I want to print 'test' when clicking MyButton

I made constructs with a function in my class but didn't work

please help me
here is my code

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'bla bla bla',
            ),
            MyButton((){print('test');}, 'my button')
          ],
        ),
```

I'm made a StatefulWidget class I called it MyButton

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  Function buttonFunction;
  String buttonName;
  MyButton(this.buttonFunction,this.buttonName);

  @override
  _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String name=widget.buttonName;
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          widget.buttonFunction;
          print('clicked $name');
        },

        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text("$name",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling your function: `widget.buttonFunction();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis "()" to call the function, instead you are just referencing it.

You are also setting a variable inside the build method which is the wrong place to declare variables, as it will re-run many times and be re-declared unnecessarily and become expensive. If you want to access the property of a value inside a String you just have to use `"String ${widget.myStringVariable}.".

I've modified your code to reflect these changes:

```
class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          widget.buttonFunction();
          print('clicked $name');
        },
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text("${widget.buttonName}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Husamuldeen Is an answer fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct. It will help other users.

Comment: Bellow the voting arrows the is a check mark. If you press it, it will turn green and Mark the answer as correct.

Comment: what should I do if that I want to use the widget.buttonName in an if statement  before the override?, please help @João Soares

Comment: You can use it like any other variable `String name = widget.buttonName;`.